# React Update state after http request in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a React app that takes initial fake data and renders in a component and now I am trying to get data from [JSON Placeolder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) service and renders in the same component.

I can successfully get data but I don't know how to update component state from the reducer function.

My Reducer function

```js
import axios from "axios";
const initState ={
  projects:[
    {id:1, title:'First project', author:'xyz', dateCreated:'3rd September, 2AM', content:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum blanditiis vel eius consequuntur facere sequi, iusto, aspernatur harum a adipisci voluptatum itaque quod nesciunt, officia aliquam placeat tempora laborum? Provident!'},
    {id:2, title:'Second project', author:'abx', dateCreated:'3rd September, 2AM',content:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum blanditiis vel eius consequuntur facere sequi, iusto, aspernatur harum a adipisci voluptatum itaque quod nesciunt, officia aliquam placeat tempora laborum? Provident!'},
    {id:3, title:'Third project', author:'juq', dateCreated:'3rd September, 2AM', content:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum blanditiis vel eius consequuntur facere sequi, iusto, aspernatur harum a adipisci voluptatum itaque quod nesciunt, officia aliquam placeat tempora laborum? Provident!'}
  ]
}
const ProjectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
    {
      console.log("Project creatred");
      break;
    }
    case 'GET_ALL_PROJECTS':
    {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response)=>
        {
          state = response.data;
          return state
          console.log(state, action);
          //dispatch({type:'GET_ALL_PROJECTS_RECEIVED', data:response.data});
          
          //I have to call render component from here becuase state now has data.
        })
      //}
    }
    case 'GET_ALL_PROJECTS_RECEIVED':
    {
      return state;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  
  return state
}

export default ProjectReducer
```

index.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import RootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(RootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider> , document.getElementById('root'));
store.dispatch({type:'GET_ALL_PROJECTS'});
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

dshboard component where I get Data and pass it to another component to render it, this code is called when component is loaded first time but does not execute after http request is completed.

```js
import React, {Component } from "react";
import Notifications from "./notifications";
import ProjectList from "../projects/projectList";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Dashboard extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div className="dahboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <ProjectList projects={this.props.projects}></ProjectList>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                        <Notifications></Notifications>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      projects:state.projectRepo.projects
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)( Dashboard)
```

I can see 3 project entries which were hard coded but I can't see any data rendered coming through http request.

Comment: Your reducer is not asynchronous. It takes a state and an action and returns the next state. To do async stuff you need to do the async stuff first, then dispatch an action to update the state. Google `redux side effects` - you can look into `redux-thunk`, or `redux-saga` for instance.

Comment: I am using redux-thunk as well, see index.js file

Comment: You should probably first take a look out the official examples including the async and real-world examples in terms of how and where you’d handle async operations such as fetch calls as well as how to structure things. Notice that async actions are happening in the action/action-creators and only dispatch once the requests resolve or reject, not in the reducer. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

Reducer is not the right place to call the API, you need to call the API in your component and then call an action with the response to update the state.

Reducer code.

```
const initState ={
  projects:[
    {id:1, title:'First project', author:'xyz', dateCreated:'3rd September, 2AM', content:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum blanditiis vel eius consequuntur facere sequi, iusto, aspernatur harum a adipisci voluptatum itaque quod nesciunt, officia aliquam placeat tempora laborum? Provident!'},
    {id:2, title:'Second project', author:'abx', dateCreated:'3rd September, 2AM',content:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum blanditiis vel eius consequuntur facere sequi, iusto, aspernatur harum a adipisci voluptatum itaque quod nesciunt, officia aliquam placeat tempora laborum? Provident!'},
    {id:3, title:'Third project', author:'juq', dateCreated:'3rd September, 2AM', content:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum blanditiis vel eius consequuntur facere sequi, iusto, aspernatur harum a adipisci voluptatum itaque quod nesciunt, officia aliquam placeat tempora laborum? Provident!'}
  ]
}
const ProjectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
    {
      console.log("Project creatred");
      break;
    }
    case 'GET_ALL_PROJECTS':
    {
        return { ...state, projects: action.payload };
    }
    case 'GET_ALL_PROJECTS_RECEIVED':
    {
      return state;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }

  return state
}

export default ProjectReducer
```

Component

```
import React, {Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Notifications from "./notifications";
import ProjectList from "../projects/projectList";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Dashboard extends Component
{
componentDidMount() {
  this.getProjects();
}
getProjects = () => {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then((response)=>
    {
      this.props.dispatch({type:'GET_ALL_PROJECTS_RECEIVED', payload:response.data});
    })
}
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div className="dahboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <ProjectList projects={this.props.projects}></ProjectList>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                        <Notifications></Notifications>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      projects:state.projectRepo.projects
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {

}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)( Dashboard)
```

Hope it will help you.